# How to change the shape of a UIButton in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6, cgrect

I am trying to make an arrow shape. I understand that it will be done with CGRect method but can you give a complete example of how it will be done in SWIFT?

Comment: Do you mean to draw a triangle in a UIView, or would you like a custom shape with some text inside?

Comment: Custom shape with text inside.
I thought it would be a custom UIButton class which I can reuse.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would probably be to use a UIButton as you suggested. Setting the font to bottom middle an setting the UIButton.currentImage to be an image of a triangle. (Or you could go the hardcore way... Created a subclass of UIView, draw a triangle there with CoreGraphics, then set the text inside the triangle using drawInRect. )  Example of CG and Text [here](https://github.com/regnerjr/BNRSolutions/blob/master/Hypnosister/Hypnosister3/HypnoView.swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done programmatically by first subclassing UIButton and overriding drawRect within it to form the shape of an arrow via bezier paths. Then simply set the title of the button to be whatever you want your text to be and position it accordingly within the shape you have drawn.

The benefit of doing it this way is that you can easily change the color of, scale and dimensions of the arrow since you control how the object is actually being drawn.

A good tool for drawing complex bezier paths is [paintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/). I'm using the trial version and can pretty easily make shapes like this now.

Comment: good one. i made arrow shape in paintCode and applied it to a custom UILabel class and it works, only problem is that it is not showing the text i have set to the label in Interface Builder.

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly why this is happening without seeing code. Check to make sure everything is linked up properly as this could be an issue. However, it might be easier for you to simply set the labeltext programmatically now. This can be done as labelname.text = "text here"